# Is there a significance test for testing that the population standard deviation is greater than zero?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, chi-squared

I am working on a project where I need to test the following hypotheses:
$H_0: &sigma; = 0
H_a: &sigma; > 0$
I am aware of the chi square test for standard deviation, that is
$&chi;^2 = \frac{(n-1)s^2}{&sigma;^2}$
However, as σ = 0, this test statistic would result in me dividing by 0. Is there any way for me to test for the standard deviation being greater than 0?

Comment: Since you state _standard deviation_ specifically, it’s fair to assume you’re assuming normally distributed samples, maybe even iid?

Comment: Note that the standard deviation is greater than zero whenever the population distribution is not constant. In most cases, this should not be difficult to detect...

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure it shapes up like this: if the population standard deviation is zero, then any sample you take from it has to be all the same value, because that's the only value with nonzero probability. So if you have a sample with more than $1$ distinct value, you can conclude with $p = 0$ that the population standard deviation is nonzero, because the sample you got is completely impossible if the null hypothesis is true. If you have a sample with all the same value, then because the sample standard deviation can't be negative and must always be at least $0,$ with $p = 1$ we fail to reject the null hypothesis, because we failed to collect sufficient evidence that the population standard deviation is nonzero.

Comment: Unless OP states it, I don’t see reason to infer a common mean.

Comment: @Aruralreader I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: You need to comment on the nature of your samples. Suppose they’re $X_1, \dots, X_N$ where $X_n = n + \varepsilon_n$ and the $\varepsilon_n$ are independent zero-mean normals with common standard deviation $\sigma$?

Comment: @Aruralreader I really don't think it's unreasonable to assume that the question is referring to a sample which all comes from the same distribution, but sure. If the means are known then the same logic of "if I see anything I don't expect, immediately reject $H_0$" applies, if we don't know anything about the means then there's nothing we can do, and if the means follow some probability distribution then I don't understand why we're modelling it this way anyway.

Comment: Stephen, on thinking it over I agree with you, I was being a bit pedantic I can see, thanks.

Comment: @Aruralreader No worries, I get where you were coming from. No harm done, no hard feelings.